# Gallio 3.4 is not loading assemblies of .NET version 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, gallio

My assemblies are in .NET framework version 4.5 and I am using gallio 3.4 but whenever I am running, gallio.echo.exe with dll is throwing exception

> System.BadImage Format Exception : could not load file
>
> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>   FileName: Winshuttle.SapTransaction.Recorder, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null FusionLog: WRN: Assembly binding
>   logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set
>   the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD)
>   to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly
>   bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry
>   value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> HResult: -2147024885

Please suggest whats the issue. Is there any other gallio version to run 4.5 assemblies

Comment: the bad image exception let me think it would rather be related to a x86/x64 issue. Is it possible you try to mix different assemblies targeting different platforms?

Comment: Yes Actually I was using any cpu as configuration due to which it is considering the dll of 64 bit whereas gallio is of 32 bit .